# Does setting a unique_together cause droping of duplicates upon migration?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have duplicates, for a pair of fields, in my database which I would like to drop.

Can I do this by simply setting `unique_together` on the pair and migrating? I am using Django 2.0. Here is the model(with the `unique_together` already added):

```
class Candle(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    open = models.FloatField()
    high = models.FloatField()
    low = models.FloatField()
    close = models.FloatField()
    volume = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Candlestick for {} at {}.'.format(self.symbol, 
                self.timestamp)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['symbol']),
            models.Index(fields=['timestamp'])
        ]
        unique_together = (('symbol', 'timestamp'),)
```

Otherwise what is the best way to drop these duplicates, and avoid the insertion of new ones? Should I go directly into PostGreSQL, drop the duplicates, and then enforce the rule?

I found these two possible solution to drop the duplicates:

1. [Looping through a queryset of the duplicates](https://gist.github.com/victorono/cd9d14b013487b8b22975512225c5b4c)
2. [Straight from SQL](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Deleting_duplicates)

Comment: You will get integrity error when you make unqiue_together of two fields which have already duplicate data.

Comment: By setting `unique_together`, you will raise an integrity error, so no that is not possible. Even if that was possible, now the question will be *which of the duplicates should be removed?*.

Comment: Assuming they are identical, in my case, it does not matter which one gets removed as long as only one remains.

Comment: Is it ok that you remove the duplicate by `symbol`? Make sure you are not running on the production database.

Comment: It's not in production. ;-) What do you mean removing by symbol?

Comment: I mean if `symbol` field value is duplicate then remove these.

Comment: I chose the SQL method to drop the duplicates and then enforced the constraint. I also added a try/except ValidationError around new inserts to this table. Solved.